# The gesture conflicts when put a webView into a scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, webview, scrollview

[image: the UI image]

you can see the picture that shows my UI , when the view loaded at
first time ,I don't want the webView scroll enabled, at this time touch any point and drag on the screen , it should be respond by backgroundScrollView . But when the headerView slides out of the screen, the responder should switch to webView , But when the webView slides to the top , and continue to slide down ,this time the responder object should switch to backGroundView.

I hope that this statement beyond can clearly expresses what I mean...

I have tried to override the hit test method in the webView :

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{

    if (self.backGroundScrollView.contentOffset.y > HeaderView.height) {
        return self(the webView);
    }
    return backGroundScrollView;
}
```

but it don't work. and if I override it in the second_ScrollView(red one), the horizontal scroll will be disabled.

so is there a perfect way to solve this problem?

Comment: why you need the yellow scroll view?

Comment: @ovo because i need the page can be scroll. including the HeaderView。

Answer (score 1):

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview) discourages embedding `UIWebView` or `UITableView` within a `UIScrollView` because it can cause unexpected behaviour:

> You should not embed `UIWebView` or `UITableView` objects in
>   `UIScrollView` objects. If you do so, unexpected behavior can result
>   because touch events for the two objects can be mixed up and wrongly
>   handled.

This is likely why you are having trouble finding a tutorial.

Comment: thank you, i think i can consider to implementation it by tableView + scrollView. but i think it's the same situation.The demand is so.